Different response headers for 302 response in Postman and Node.js axios
I am making a POST request from Node.js backend to an external website (mirror.codeforces.com). In both Postman and Node.js axios response, I receive status code 302 (I have set maxRedirects = 0), but the response headers are significantly different. There is only one redirect, and I need to obtain the 'set-cookie' header from the redirect response.
Here is the postman response header (taken from Postman console):
Server: kittenx
Date: Wed, 04 Dec 2024 09:42:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private,no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: X-User-Sha1=63425e0090d62898166c5c9b81df08c303901c5a; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Thu, 04-Dec-2025 09:42:21 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: X-User=6bda2511d1276d70f78a12c28e42ba5fbc25832f53e1abe635d83f3b21edd64d6896ee63fb14fdf7; Max-Age=2592000; Expires=Fri, 03-Jan-2025 09:42:21 GMT; Path=/
Location: https://mirror.codeforces.com/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frontend: front932212
X-Trace-Id: y-03olMfFrxCP1aH8EDH80OcdPtU2g
Server-Timing: tid;desc="y-03olMfFrxCP1aH8EDH80OcdPtU2g",front;dur=0.596

Here is the Node.js response header (logged to terminal using res.headers):
Object [AxiosHeaders] {
  server: 'kittenx',
  date: 'Wed, 04 Dec 2024 10:17:35 GMT',
  'content-length': '0',
  connection: 'close',
  location: '/',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=86400',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-frame-options': 'sameorigin',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-frontend': 'front932210',
  'x-trace-id': 'RGgdGL7Uq1IT4hKwR88b1pomn6HsBA',
  'server-timing': 'tid;desc="RGgdGL7Uq1IT4hKwR88b1pomn6HsBA",front;dur=0.131'
}

Here is Node.js code + cookieString and Postman code for the post request, for reference.
The cookies are visible in, and are being set in Postman and browser, these are the properties of cookies as seen on browser. I am expecting X-User-Sha1 and X-User to be found in response headers.
PS: I am unable to confirm if the POST request was successful. It is possible that even unsuccessful requests are redirected with 302, in that case what could be the reason that Postman requests are successful while Node.js requests aren't? They both have identical Headers, and cookies (as seen in above picture links).
PPS: In Postman (automatic redirects off), making POST request, then deleting the X-User-Sha1 and X-User cookies, and then making a GET request to home page of the site WORKS.
